# Force light mode when browser is set to dark mode

Tags: html, css, darkmode

When the browser is set to dark mode a filter is set which makes my sections darker. I don't want that to happen. I tried forcing light mode with:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="only light">
```

but this doesn't work on all browsers. I don't know how to work around or fix this.

Dark mode on:
[image: Dark mode on]

Dark mode off:
[image: Dark mode off]

Comment: Try using `only` since it's the same as saying `light only`. You can also set `:root { color-scheme: light; }`

Comment: I gave you wrong information unfortunately. The question has been edited

Comment: Even with the edit, my comment stands. I would try testing the `:root { color-scheme: light;}`

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: There is no workaround this. Since you can not force anything on the user, they are always allowed to override. `:root { color-scheme: only light; }` works for chrome. On other browsers, you will have to give each element a specific color if you want it to look a specific way.

Comment: I assigned a specific color to my divs. It is as if a blackout filter is placed on them and this is horrible because it turns white into the color of poop xD

Comment: share you css first. I can see your divs are semi-transparent. and body is visible through them. if you do not set a color on body this issue will arise.

Comment: https://github.com/Manux895/EsameDiStato. To this code I simply added what you told me in the css and removed the meta tag

Answer (score 1):

You can not force color-scheme on the user, users are allowed to override it. You can use `:root{ color-scheme: only light}` on chrome but it may not work on other browsers. I can see your div(s) are semi-transparent and body is visible through them. if you do not set a color on body this issue will arise. It's better you give `body` a color to avoid any color changes based on `color-scheme`. In the code below I have given body a color and also set color-scheme to dark, still the dark mode is not visible because  `body` has a color. None of these will work with **experimental force-dark-mode** features on some devices, that is purely on user(same way as you can't do anything if user turn on low-blue-light mode on their device and it turns your webpage yellowish) .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="color-scheme" content="dark">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style='color: red;background-color:rgb(255,255,235);'>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe perspiciatis, dicta ducimus quos a et molestiae vero quasi nisi magni unde eius impedit ut possimus dolorum dolor, dolorem, error dolore!</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also use media queries to set the styles when darkmode is enables as :

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){
body{
color:gray;
background:white;
}
}
```

Comment: @TheManux try running this code in your browser.

Comment: The described behavior is also shown by setting a color to the body

Comment: I just ran the code with your github page. It works perfectly well. what browser are you viewing it on?

Comment: It works because it is not updated. That version has the meta tag I mentioned in the question; this doesn't work on browsers like the one from samsung

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-bird-nw3stk?file=/style.css   check this code and tell me exactly what issue is there in the output, like which div or section has wrong color.

Comment: I have exactly the same effect as shown in the pictures featured in the question. The second case is the desired effect even with dark mode, while the first is what I get when dark mode is on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254194/discussion-between-aniket-pandey-and-the-manux).